# mturk multiple qualifications for locations and acceptance rate not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, mechanicalturk

When I use --qualification-requirements with mturk create-hit-type, it is only picking up the location and not the acceptance rating. How is it possible to make both qualifications mandatory? Could someone please help me with this problem?

```
--qualification-requirements QualificationTypeId="000000000000000000L0",Comparator="GreaterThanOrEqualTo",IntegerValues=[90],RequiredToPreview=true --qualification-requirements QualificationTypeId="00000000000000000071",Comparator="EqualTo",LocaleValues=[{Country="US"}],RequiredToPreview=true
```

When I merge both

```
--qualification-requirements QualificationTypeId="000000000000000000L0",Comparator="GreaterThanOrEqualTo",IntegerValues=[90],RequiredToPreview=true, QualificationTypeId="00000000000000000071",Comparator="EqualTo",LocaleValues=[{Country="US"}],RequiredToPreview=true
```

It gives the error

```
An error occurred (ParameterValidationError) when calling the CreateHITType operation: The value "90" is not valid for the parameter IntegerValue. IntegerValue must be null when used with the EqualTo comparator.. (1515942437408 s)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried to get help from all most anywhere and finally, Amazon Mturk responded to my tweet. I contacted them directly and after more than a week, I got the following response, that it was the ',' in-between both that caused the problem.

The corrected code is

```
--qualification-requirements QualificationTypeId="000000000000000000L0",Comparator="GreaterThanOrEqualTo",IntegerValues=[90],RequiredToPreview=true QualificationTypeId="00000000000000000071",Comparator="EqualTo",LocaleValues=[{Country="US"}],RequiredToPreview=true
```

I hope it would help others with the same problem.